# ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, redis, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to run rq worker in ubuntu but when I type

```
rq worker
```

It gives me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/rq/utils.py", line 169, in utcparse
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(string, _TIMESTAMP_FORMAT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/rq/worker.py", line 508, in work
    result = self.dequeue_job_and_maintain_ttl(timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/rq/worker.py", line 574, in dequeue_job_and_maintain_ttl
    result = self.queue_class.dequeue_any(self.queues, timeout,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/rq/queue.py", line 539, in dequeue_any
    job = job_class.fetch(job_id, connection=connection)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/rq/job.py", line 303, in fetch
    job.refresh()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/rq/job.py", line 515, in refresh
    self.restore(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/rq/job.py", line 478, in restore
    self.started_at = str_to_date(obj.get('started_at'))
```

I am queueing a simple task from another file hello.py, the code:

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

and this is my main.py code:

```
from flask import Flask
from redis import Redis

from hello import add
from rq import Queue

q = Queue(connection=Redis())


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    q.enqueue(add, 3, 7)
    return "Task enqueued"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

It is queueing the things in redis-server but it doesn't have a worker to run things, I just want a worker running in ubuntu. And the redis-server is hosted locally. I checked even the task is enqueueing properly but it is showing that their are 0 workers. I don't know what else to write but feel free to ask anything regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the error you provided, there is no timestamp ('') being sent to rq :

```
ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
```

Check to see if you have a conflicting package called python-rq installed per this issue :

https://github.com/rq/rq/issues/1309

If not, check that your locale is set correctly in Ubuntu and the 'date' command produce the expected result. Next check that the Python also returns the correct date :

```
import datetime;
print(datetime.datetime.now())
```